# HDMI source to DisplayPort monitor

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, displayport

I recently bought a cable that I though was HDMI to DisplayPort, to use on my GeForce GT710, but when I plug the cable into my computer and monitor I get no signal. Is there any way I can get it to work? Now after some research I'm worried that the cable was actually meant for going the other way.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No, I definitely tried that and it's not working. Tried on a Windows 10 machine as well.

Comment: @tatsu We can assume "not working" because of the precedent sentence. And no, video cable *adapters* are not always "both ways". IMO the OP is correct in assuming theirs is DP -> HDMI.

Comment: oh, I would have never thought that. all my hdmi to dvi cables for example work both ways. I stand corrected. I also thought OP though hdmi to hdmi and display port to display port cables worked only in one dirrection. And if it didn't work on windows either then I don't see how this is an ubuntu question and not off-topic.